# Problem in putting a background image in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, backgrounds

I am having problems with putting a background image in the title-page of `Beamer`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan} %background color
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=blue} %colore titoli
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan} %colore e background in un comando


%%% duplicated <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%\usepackage{tikz}
%%\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
%%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
%%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
%%\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=violet!50}  

  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
 %\usetikzlibrary{calc} %rido <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt}% all frames will have cobalt bullets
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball] %all bullets
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt,bg=bluegray}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

%\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}}


%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove the navigation bar
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{0.2 cm}
        
        \Large
        %\color{cobalt}
        \textbf{UNI NAME}\\
        %\vspace*{1 cm}
        %\includegraphics[height=50pt]{logo.jpeg} 
        
        
        %\vspace{1cm}
        \large
        Dipartiment\\
        %\vspace{1cm}
        \small
        kind of degree\\
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \large
        Thesis
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \large
        \color{cobalt}
        \textbf{title}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \footnotesize
        \color{black}
        Candidato:\\
        \normalsize
        \textbf{name}\\
        
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        
        %\vfill
        
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
 \footnotesize 
 Relatore

 \small  
 Prof.ssa \textbf{name 1} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
 \footnotesize 
  Correlatore

 \small
 Prof. \textbf{name 2} 
\end{minipage}
    
\vspace{1cm}
        
\small
year 2019-2020 

        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=bluegray!4} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=bluegray!50} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title first slide} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed

%\begin{figure}[h]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\centering%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{itemize}
\item bla blla
\item gla gla
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I was trying:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.3] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}};}
```

but I'd like the background only on the title page.

P.S. I don't even know how to remove the first page that displays the date.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

I rearranged the title code. It is better to keep font size changes in braces to limit their scope and not to confuse other spaces defined in terms of font size.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.8}    

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt}% all frames will have cobalt bullets
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball] %all bullets
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt,bg=bluegray}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove the navigation bar

\date{} % <<<<< added
\begin{document}
    
    \title{% <<<<< added
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{0.1 cm}        
        {\Large \textbf{UNI NAME}}\\
        {\large Dipartiment}\\
        {\small kind of degree}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        {\large Thesis} \\      
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        {\large \color{cobalt}  \textbf{title}} \\  
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \color{black}
        {\footnotesize  Candidato:}\\
        \textbf{name}\\     
        \vspace{0.4cm}
        \begin{minipage}{6cm}
            \centering  \footnotesize 
                Relatore    \\      
            {\small Prof.ssa \textbf{name 1} }
        \end{minipage}\hfill    
        \begin{minipage}{4cm}
            \centering  \footnotesize 
            Correlatore\\           
            {\small     Prof. \textbf{name 2}}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \vspace{0.7cm}          
        {\small year 2019-2020}
    \end{center}
}
            
    
{%
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
}   
    
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=bluegray!4} %
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt,bg=bluegray!50} %<

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title first slide} %<

\begin{itemize}
    \item bla blla
    \item gla gla
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Comment: thanks a lot, but how doo I set the 'opacity', for example '0.2'

Comment: It is already in the background. You do not need opacity.  Take a closer look to "title` and see it is above the crossing lines.